# Error when validating form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have some problems with this form validation. Now, my code is something like this:

```html
@model MassiveGenerationModel

<form id="FormGenerateMassive" name="FormGenerateMassive">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DiscountId)
    <table id="tableMassiveGeneration">
        <tr>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CouponPrefix)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CouponPrefix)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CouponPrefix)
        </tr>
        <tr>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CouponNumber)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CouponNumber)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CouponNumber)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CouponLength)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CouponLength)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CouponLength)
            </td>
    </table>
    <input type="button" id="GenerateMassiveButton" value="Massive generation"  onclick ="CreateMassiveSubmit()">
    <div style="display:none" id="messageGM">
        <span id="messageFromServer"></span>
    </div>
</form>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 

    function CreateMassiveSubmit() {

        $("#GenerateMassiveButton").prop("disabled", true);
        $("div#messageGM").css("display", "none");

        var CreateMassiveSubmitCall = function (data) {
            $("div#messageGM").css("display", "block");
            $("span#messageFromServer").text(data.Message);
            $("#GenerateMassiveButton").prop("disabled", false);

        }

        var CreateMassiveSubmitError = function (err) {
            $("#GenerateMassiveButton").prop("disabled", false);
            alert(err.Message);
        }

        if ($("#FormGenerateMassive").valid()) {
            $("#FormGenerateMassive").postFormAjax("/Discount/MassiveGenerationCoupons", CreateMassiveSubmitCall, CreateMassiveSubmitError);
        }
    }
  
    $.fn.postFormAjax = function (url, success, error) {
        var data = this.serializeObject();
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: success,
            error: error
        });
    }

    $.fn.serializeObject = function () {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function () {
            var nameDest = this.name;
            var nameSplited = nameDest.split(".");
            if (nameSplited.length > 1) {
                nameDest = nameSplited[1];
            }
            if (o[nameDest] !== undefined) {
                if (!o[nameDest].push) {
                    o[nameDest] = [o[nameDest]];
                }
                o[nameDest].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[nameDest] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
</script>
```

But jquery validator return an error: "Cannot read property 'form' of undefined". What's happening? I don't understand why if all properties have value the form can't validate itself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By "jquery validator" do you mean the .valid() call? Also, can you post the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: Exactly, $("#FormGenerateMassive").valid() call return the error "Cannot read property 'form' of undefined".

Only shows this error.

Comment: If you use Chrome's debugger it should give you a call stack.. if not, you can get the call stack by setting a "Break on unhandled exception" breakpoint and looking at the stack. Meanwhile, I noticed you aren't using $(document).ready listener before doing your DOM manipulation - your javascript is defined after your body so I don't think this would have an effect but why not just try wrapping your javascript in $(document).ready(function() { })?

Comment: Mmmm I checked this, but is not the solution... I just saw this form is inside other form... Maybe this is the problem... And for this reason isn't validating the form.